# Uploading image to web server using FTP

Tags: php, image, laravel

I'm pretty new to laravel and I'm currently stuck at uploading images to web server via ftp. I've followed this [article/tutorial](https://artisansweb.net/how-to-upload-images-to-another-server-through-ftp-in-laravel/) to set everything up, but I can't get it to work, I get this error:

> Can't write image data to path (/storage/ssd4/849/3099849/ponijeri/public/uploads/1523970289image1.jpg)

Note: I was transferring files/images from my desktop to uploads folder in my project files while the website was still in development (localhost), and everything was working fine until I decided to upload files to my live website on web server.

Controller code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $findObject = Accommodation::find($id);
    $findObject->update($request->all());

    Gallery::destroy('objects_id', $id);
    foreach ($request['img'] as $img) {
        $gallery = new Gallery();
        $gallery->objects_id=$id;
        $name = time() . $img->getClientOriginalName(); // prepend the time (integer) to the original file name
        $img->move('uploads', $name); // move it to the 'uploads' directory (public/uploads)
        $gallery->img=$name;
        $gallery->save();

        // // create instance of Intervention Image
        $img = Image::make('uploads/'.$name);
        $img->save(public_path().'/uploads/'.$name);

        Storage::disk('ftp')->put($gallery, fopen($request->file('img[]'), 'r+'));

    }

    $headerImage = $request['headerImage'];
    $name = time() . $headerImage->getClientOriginalName(); // prepend the time (integer) to the original file name
    $headerImage->move('uploads', $name); // move it to the 'uploads' directory (public/uploads)
    $findObject->headerImage=$name;
    $findObject->save();

    // // create instance of Intervention Image
    $headerImage = Image::make('uploads/'.$name);
    $headerImage->save(public_path().'/uploads/'.$name);

    Storage::disk('ftp')->put($headerImage, fopen($request->file('headerImage'), 'r+'));

    return redirect('/objects');

}
```

FTP configuration:

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
        'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
        'root' => '/public/uploads'
    ],
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You have write permission for storage folder on web server ?

Comment: I just checked, seems like everything is okay with my permissions.

Comment: give 777 permission to storage folder

Comment: I already did it, my permissions are set to 777

Comment: You should avoid ftp anyway nowaday, dive around `ssh`. Can be used graphicaly too, in ubuntu and probably other os from the file explorer «connect to server» then drag drop! Check also rsync!

Comment: @Faraz Irfan  «give 777 permission to storage folder» NO seriously don't do that! This is giving execution right to everyone. Very easy to hack then, uploading a devil bash script, then it will be executed just by visiting the url! Meaning full data breach, full control of the machine including system files!!!

Comment: So I shouldn't mess with permissions? @Cryptopat

Comment: At least not 777. You just need writing right, for you only. dive around!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `relative path`

> public_path()

on production server, please try to use `absolute path` instead.

Comment: Sorry, this is first time hearing about a absolute path, how should I implement it? Copy full destination path instead of public_path()?

Comment: Yes,for example /var/www/your/site/public/uploads.
 https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: I will try this in a bit. I will notify you if it works

Comment: I tried everything, my final path was: $headerImage->save('/var/www/ponijeritest/ponijeri/public/uploads/'.$name); and I still got the same error.  @SonDang